# what kind of error this Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Comment: A pretty descriptive one... Try what it suggests.

Comment: The full documentation for this is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is the default generic error message in ASP.NET.

Re the more specific "what kind of error"; impossible for us to say; it could be a configuration error in web.config, it could be problems talking to the database, it could simply need a hug and some quiet time. Like the message says, either enable remote debug output, or look at the site *from the server*, and it'll tell you what is *actually* happening. Or look in the error log (event-viewer by default), which is perhaps more useful.

Note you can replace the error page with something more... *user friendly* if you like. Like the lolcatz on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web.config file to have this

```
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
   </system.web>
```